# How to show an EditText on checking Check Box in Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox

I want to add **check box** in my **android activity** such that when the **check box is checked** one more **editText** should appear in the activity..
Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 2 `EditText` and make one's visibility `Gone` by default. Then check if the checkbox is checked or unchecked! If checked make 2nd `EditText`'s visibility `Visible`.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a listener which will perform this function..

```
public void addView(LinearLayout lay, EditText etxt){
     lay.addView(etxt);
}
public EditText editText(Context context, int id, LinearLayout.LayoutParams params,int paddings){
    EditText ib = new EditText(context);
    ib.setId(id);
    //ib.setBackgroundResource(Background);
    // you can use this for a layout //
    ib.setLayoutParams(params);
    // you can use padding option by getting an array as argument
    ib.setPadding(pad,pad,pad,pad);

    return ib;

}
```

You can use this like:

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);


// Now Show the EditText inside the View
chkBox= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Check_box);
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
               EditText eTxt = editText(context,502/*id here*/,lp,0); 
               addView(main,eTxt);
        }
   }
 });
```